# In Cirq, how do you display circuit diagrams that are "prettier" than the ones displayed by default?

Tags: programming, cirq

This is a duplicate of a question that was asked on the [Cirq issues page](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/3885). I'm duplicating this question to increase it's visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to print circuits in Cirq is by calling `print(circuit)`: which prints the text diagram representation of the circuit. A "prettier" representation can be displayed with `SVGCircuit`. In a Jupyter notebook,

```python
import cirq
from cirq.contrib.svg import SVGCircuit

a, b = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)
SVGCircuit(cirq.Circuit(cirq.X(a), cirq.CNOT(a,b)))
```

outputs:
[image]

`SVGCircuit` is a work-in-progress. Please add comments explaining what problems you run into on the [Circuit.*repr_svg* with nice diagrams for ipython](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/2313) issue.